# Calling beam.io.WriteToBigQuery in a beam.DoFn

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've created a dataflow template with some parameters. When I write the data to BigQuery, I would like to make use of these parameters to determine which table it is supposed to write to. I've tried calling WriteToBigQuery in a ParDo as  suggested in the following link.

[How can I write to Big Query using a runtime value provider in Apache Beam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217902/how-can-i-write-to-big-query-using-a-runtime-value-provider-in-apache-beam)

The pipeline ran successfully but it is not creating or loading data to BigQuery. Any idea what might be the issue?

```
def run():
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
  pipeline_options.view_as(DebugOptions).experiments = ['use_beam_bq_sink']

  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    custom_options = pipeline_options.view_as(CustomOptions)

    _ = (
      p
      | beam.Create([None])
      | 'Year to periods' >> beam.ParDo(SplitYearToPeriod(custom_options.year))
      | 'Read plan data' >> beam.ParDo(GetPlanDataByPeriod(custom_options.secret_name))
      | 'Transform record' >> beam.Map(transform_record)
      | 'Write to BQ' >> beam.ParDo(WritePlanDataToBigQuery(custom_options.year))
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

```
class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
  @classmethod
  def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
    parser.add_value_provider_argument('--year', type=int)
    parser.add_value_provider_argument('--secret_name', type=str)
```

```
class WritePlanDataToBigQuery(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self, year_vp):
    self._year_vp = year_vp

  def process(self, element):
    year = self._year_vp.get()

    table = f's4c.plan_data_{year}'
    schema = {
      'fields': [ ...some fields properties ]
    }

    beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
      table=table,
      schema=schema,
      create_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
      write_disposition=BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
      method=beam.io.WriteToBigQuery.Method.FILE_LOADS
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have instantiated the PTransform `beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery` inside the `process` method of your `DoFn`. There are a couple of problems here:

- The `process` method is called for each element of the input PCollection. It is not used for building the pipeline graph. This approach to dynamically constructing the graph will not work.
- Once you move it out of the `DoFn`, you need to apply the PTransform `beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery` to a PCollection for it to have any effect. See the [Beam pydoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.21.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#writing-data-to-bigquery) or the [Beam tutorial documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/).

To create a derived value provider for your table name, you would need a "nested" value provider. Unfortunately this is [not supported for the Python SDK](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-nestedvalueprovider). You can use the value provider option directly, though.

As an advanced option, you may be interested in trying out "flex templates" which essentially package up your whole program as a docker image and execute it with parameters.

Comment: I noticed that if I use `use_beam_bq_sink` flag, I can pass a value provider directly to `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` table argument. Hence, I just let the caller of the template decides which table it needs to update to. I've tried flex template but I'm not able to get it working. I kept getting _transient errors_.

Comment: Edited the answer: you can use the value provider directly. You just can't build a new string from the value provider.

Answer (score 0):

If the objective is for the code to accept parameters instead of a hard-coded string for the table path, here is a way to achieve that:

- Add the table parameters as **CustomOptions**
- Inside your run function add the **CustomOptions** parameters as
  default string

```
...

class CustomOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--gcs_input_file_path',
            type=str,
            help='GCS Input File Path'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--project_id',
            type=str,
            help='GCP ProjectID'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--dataset',
            type=str,
            help='BigQuery DataSet Name'
        )
        parser.add_value_provider_argument(
            '--table',
            type=str,
            help='BigQuery Table Name'
        )

def run(argv=None):

    pipeline_option = PipelineOptions()
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_option)
    custom_options = pipeline_option.view_as(CustomOptions)
    pipeline_option.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    pipeline_option.view_as(DebugOptions).experiments = ['use_beam_bq_sink']

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--gcp_project_id',
        type=str,
        help='GCP ProjectID',
        default=str(custom_options.project_id)
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--dataset',
        type=str,
        help='BigQuery DataSet Name',
        default=str(custom_options.dataset)
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--table',
        type=str,
        help='BigQuery Table Name',
        default=str(custom_options.table)
    )

    static_options, _ = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    path = static_options.gcp_project_id + ":" + static_options.dataset + "." + static_options.table

    data = (
            pipeline
            | "Read from GCS Bucket" >>
            beam.io.textio.ReadFromText(custom_options.gcs_input_file_path)
            | "Parse Text File" >>
            beam.ParDo(Split())
            | 'WriteToBigQuery' >>
            beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                path,
                schema=Schema,
                create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND
            )
    )

    result = pipeline.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

- Pass the table path at pipeline construction time in the shell file

```
python template.py \
  --dataset dataset_name \
  --table table_name \
  --project project_name \
  --runner DataFlowRunner \
  --region region_name \
  --staging_location gs://bucket_name/staging \
  --temp_location gs://bucket_name/temp \
  --template_location gs://bucket_name/templates/template_name
```