# Unable to pass BigQuery table name as ValueProvider to dataflow template

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to pass BigQuery table name as a run time parameters to my dataflow template as simply as this:

```
class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input', type=str, help='BigQuery table reference DATASET.TABLE')
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--output', type=str, help='BigQuery table reference DATASET.TABLE')

def run(argv=None):    
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)

    # Query
    query = f"""
    SELECT * FROM `{user_options.input}`
    WHERE last_scrape_date > (SELECT max(last_scrape_date) from `{user_options.output}`)
    """
    (p
     | 'Read from BQ Table' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(query=query, use_standard_sql=True))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
         beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
             '{user_options.output}',
             schema=schema,
             # Creates the table in BigQuery if it does not yet exist.
             create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
             # Deletes all data in the BigQuery table before writing.
             write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)))
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Per recommendations from these [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59217902/how-can-i-write-to-big-query-using-a-runtime-value-provider-in-apache-beam) and [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053420/calling-beam-io-writetobigquery-in-a-be), I add the `--experiment=use_beam_bq_sink` flag to my command line. The template is rendered successfully but I have this error when launching the template

```
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpBadRequestError: HttpError accessing <https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/vf-scrapers/jobs?alt=json>: response: <{'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin, Referer', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 15 Dec 2020 23:25:17 GMT', 'server': 'ESF', 'cache-control': 'private', 'x-xss-protection': '0', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': '400', 'content-length': '500', '-content-encoding': 'gzip'}>, content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Table name \"RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: None)\" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Table name \"RuntimeValueProvider(option: input, type: str, default_value: None)\" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I tried adding the `.get()` method to `f'{user_options.input}'` and received the same error.

#### Edit:

There's a ticket to this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1440 but I don't understand the conclusion thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Runtime parameters, like your Bigquery table names, are represented during pipeline construction as `ValueProvider` objects, not as string literals. You can see in your output that `user_options.input` is output as a stringified `RuntimeValueProvider`. But the fix is very simple in this case; Pass the object in directly without converting it to a string, like so:

```
beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
             user_options.output,
             schema=schema,
             ...
```

This is because in Dataflow templates, pipeline construction happens before runtime parameters are passed. Your input and output parameters haven't been defined yet when this code is called. Instead, the ValueProvider acts as a placeholder that will allow retrieving the parameter during runtime, once it's been defined.

Comment: it works for `WriteToBigQuery` thanks! It still doesnt work for Read though

Comment: @pa-nguyen yes, for ReadFromBigQuery, there is a bug.. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12514

I created a pull request for that: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15040

Hope it will be fixed in the next release (2.31.0).