# AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute 'projectId'

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am trying to run a apache beam pipeline in Dataflow runner; The job reads data from a bigquery table and write data to a database.

I am running the job with classic template option in dataflow - means first I will have to stage the pipeline and then run it with appropriate argument.

My pipeline options is as below

```
options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    importer_options = options.view_as(ImporterOptions)
    google_options = options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        p | 'BigQuery Read' >> beam.io.ReadFromBigQuery(
            table=importer_options.input_table)
```

The ImportOptions is currently accepting the input_table as an argument.

```
parser.add_value_provider_argument('--input-table',
                                           help='The bigquery input table in the format dataset.table_name')
```

But running the pipeline throws me an error like below

> File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py",
> line 791, in split if not self.table_reference.projectId:
> AttributeError: 'RuntimeValueProvider' object has no attribute
> 'projectId'

Anyone has any idea what am I missing here.

I am building the template using the below command.

> python -m main 
> --runner DataflowRunner 
> --project test-project 
> --region=europe-west1 
> --staging_location gs://test/staging_python 
> --temp_location gs://test/test 
> --template_location gs://test/templates_python/test \

**Note** - I tried running the pipeline by providing the fully qualified table name against the input_table (means, including the project id), but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

we are facing same issue, it is a bug since version 2.26.0 which is released at the end of 2020.

A bug report is created: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12514

And pull request is available now: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/15040

Hope it will be fixed in the next release (2.31.0).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [flex templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates) which don't require value providers, among other restrictions lifted.