# Apache Beam Pipeline to read from REST API runs locally but not on Dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been trying to get my pipeline to run with a classic template on Dataflow.

The pipeline is supposed to read runtime parameters `from_date` and `to_date`and pass those on to a REST API. The answer coming back from the API should then be written into a bigquery table.

It runs without any errors on Dataflow but my data does *simply not appear in the gbq table that is the data sink*.
When I execute it locally, it works like a charm: no errors and I can write to gbq using a service account and local files.

I suspect that I misunderstand what is available to the pipeline steps in the different environments and that no data is actually passed along the pipeline.

The `requests` package might not be available on the Dataflow runner, but I would expect an error message...

When I tried to run it on dataflow but wrote to text (commented line below), a folder was created on cloud storage but no file appeared inside.

Also I suspect that this is why I cannot get any of my debug messages to show up in the monitoring UI.

Help much appreciated - here is my pipeline code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

import logging
import argparse

# Beam/Dataflow related imports
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions, GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.options.value_provider import RuntimeValueProvider

# Handling of API calls
import requests
import json


class get_api_data(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.debug("fetching api data")

    def process(self, dates):

        bearer_token = "api_secret"

        from_date = str(dates[0])
        to_date = str(dates[1])

        logging.debug("Now fetching from ", from_date, " to ", to_date)

        payload = {'stuff': 'stuff',
                   'from': from_date,
                   'to': to_date,
                   'other_stuff': 'other_stuff'
                   }

        payload = json.dumps(payload)

        headers = {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token,
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                  }

        r = requests.post("api_url", data= payload, headers=headers)

        return [line.decode("utf-8") for line in r.iter_lines()][1:]


class Split(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):

        try:
            pid, date, another_kpi, yet_another_kpi = element.split(",")
            logging.debug(" | ".join(element.split(",")) )
        except ValueError:
            logging.error(" | ".join(element.split(",")) )

        return [{
            'pid':str(pid),
            'date':str(date),
            'another_kpi':int(another_kpi),
            'yet_another_kpi':float(yet_another_kpi)
        }]


class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--to_date', dest='to_date', type=str) 
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--from_date', dest='from_date', type=str)


def run(argv=None):
  
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    path_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)

    print("Google Cloud Options: ", pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions))

    from_date = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions).from_date
    to_date = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions).to_date

    logging.debug("Data from ", from_date, " to ", to_date)

    table_spec = bigquery.TableReference(
        projectId='my_project',
        datasetId='my_dataset',
        tableId='my_table')

    table_schema = 'pid:STRING, date:STRING, another_kpi:INT64, yet_another_kpi:FLOAT64'

    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    ingest_data = (
        p1
        | 'pass dates' >> beam.Create([[from_date, to_date]])
        | 'fetch API data' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data()) 
        | 'split records' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
        | 'write into gbq' >> beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery(table = table_spec, schema=table_schema, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE ,create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
        #| 'write to text' >> beam.io.WriteToText("./test_v2.csv")
    )

    result = p1.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    run()
```

Comment: Also, if anyone knows how to throw an error and stop the pipeline if it runs dry, i.e. no more data is passed along that would help me debug.

Comment: Do you tell Dataflow to install `requests` using requirements.txt? https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/

Comment: As per https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#version-250_1, requests is already installed, also, as I mentioned no errors regarding this module.

Comment: After testing with your code, I narrowed down the issue to be in write disposition, as I see rows when I use WRITE_APPEND. Which SDK version are you using? Is this in your SDK? https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/10668/files#diff-787bc20afbd460bd6dd0aa0239c0a81e469de55c54ef9f642e1ea206d2584541R338

Comment: Actually found the solution a minute ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240058/ways-of-using-value-provider-parameter-in-python-apache-beam).

Comment: Did you try the dataflow Runner? Making it work locally was never a problem. 

After implementing Pablos comment in this issue above, everything worked as expected. In Java there is also a method create.ofValueProvider but I hven't found an equivalent in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the ValueProvider in combination with `Create` is apparently forbidden, although I did not get an error message.

I solved it by using:

```py
class OutputValueProviderFn(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, vp1, vp2):
       self.vp1 = vp1
       self.vp2 = vp2

    def process(self, unused_elm):
        logging.info("Providing dates: ", self.vp1.get(), self.vp2.get() )
        yield [self.vp1.get(), self.vp2.get()]
...

from_date = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions).from_date
to_date = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions).to_date

pipel = (
        p1
        | 'Start Pipeline' >> beam.Create([None])
        | 'Read from and to date' >> beam.ParDo(OutputValueProviderFn(from_date, to_date))
        | 'fetch API data' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data())
        ...
    )
```

Inspiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240058/ways-of-using-value-provider-parameter-in-python-apache-beam)