# Python Apache Beam error "InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for" when request api url with spaces

Tags: python, python-requests, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Following example from [Apache Beam Pipeline to read from REST API runs locally but not on Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65582147/apache-beam-pipeline-to-read-from-rest-api-runs-locally-but-not-on-dataflow) pipeline requests data from api with

```
response = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(self.USER, self.PASSWORD), headers=headers)
```

where url string

```
url = "https://host:port/car('power%203')/speed"
```

Pipeline fails with error, notice extra `\` around `'power%203`:

```
InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '(("https://host:post/car(\'power%203\')/speed",),)' [while running 'fetch API data']
```

Idea is to develop and test pipelines locally and then run production on gcp dataflow. Request works outside pipeline, but fails inside Python Apache Beam pipeline. Pipeline executed on `DirectRunner` from WSL2 Ubuntu conda pyhton 3.9 environment or cloud jupyter hub still returns same error. Please find full pipeline example below:

```
import logging
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import requests
import json
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth

class get_api_data(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url,
        self.USER = 'user' 
        self.PASSWORD = 'password'

    def process(self, buffer=[]):        
        logging.info(self.url)
        headers = {
            'Prefer': f'data.maxpagesize=2000',
        }        
        response = requests.get(self.url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(self.USER, self.PASSWORD), headers=headers)
        buffer = response.json()['value']
        return buffer


class Split(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        try:
            etag = element['etag']
            car_id = element['carID']
            power = element['power']
            speed = element['speed']
        except ValueError as e:
            logging.error(e)

        return [{
            'etag': str(etag),
            'car_id': str(car_id),
            'power': int(power),
            'speed': float(speed),
        }]

def run(argv=None):   
    url = "https://host:port/car('power%203')/speed"
    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    ingest_data = (
        p1
        | 'Start Pipeline' >> beam.Create([None])
        | 'fetch API data' >> beam.ParDo(get_api_data(url)) 
        | 'split records' >> beam.ParDo(Split())
        | 'write to text' >> beam.io.WriteToText("./test_v2.csv")
    )

    result = p1.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

It got me really confused and I would be grateful if someone could share any suggestions or comments on why url string got distorted.

Comment: Isn't that \ with ' making an escape char just to print raw url? I think it is created for knowing that ' is in url, not quoting or ending a quote

Comment: @Faekr could you elaborate please? Is it possible to avoid such creation?

Comment: I think it's rather bug due to the first two parenthesis, it can't detect https schema imho, I will try to reproduce it on my own and will be back with answer

Comment: Could you please tell me as follows -> Are you sure or not missing something in function run with field `pipeline_options`?

Comment: Oh, probably know the answer is the comma next to url in constructor in your class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the comma next to url in `get_api_data` class - it should fix the problem

```
class get_api_data(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.USER = 'user' 
        self.PASSWORD = 'password'
```